# Error instantiating class:class:null java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jmeter

Use Selenium JUnit Java + JMeter for Load testing.

In Eclipse started the test, everything is ok, after make a JAR file and put it in apache/lib/junit directory, starting JMeter choose this JAR file, and it's crashed with error. I was reading a lot of answer on stackoverflow and other siter, but nothing find that can help me.

Here's log:

```
2015/06/10 18:10:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/06/10 18:10:49 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler: Error instantiating class:class LoadTestGuppy.LoadTestGuppy.AppTest:null java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

and code:

```
package LoadTestGuppy.LoadTestGuppy;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import junit.framework.TestCase;


public class AppTest extends TestCase {
    private WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public AppTest(){}

    public AppTest(String text){
        super(text);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://barracuda-qa.ko.kodak.com/d2l/faces/Login.jsp");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTestLoad() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authLogin")).sendKeys("some222");
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:authPassword")).sendKeys("222");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm:btnLogin")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='log']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='logout']")).click();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

What it can be?

Answer (score 0):

**Try removing these line**

InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor

```
public AppTest(){}

        public AppTest(String text){
            super(text);
        }
```

You can try reinstalling the jar file see if that works

Comment: I added this constructor just because I have an error, and after I don't. Now I did how you told me, and have the same error message and one new: 2015/06/11 09:08:27 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler: Trying to find constructor with one String parameter returned error: LoadTestGuppy.LoadTestGuppy.AppTest.<init>(java.lang.String) 
2015/06/11 09:08:52 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler: Error instantiating class:class LoadTestGuppy.LoadTestGuppy.AppTest:null java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: I changed smth, and I have not errors, JMeter give me back 1000 failed code. 'FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
  driver.get("http://barracuda-qa.ko.kodak.com/d2l/faces/Login.jsp");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();' May be it's because of Firefox, I'll try smth

Comment: Try running your test on selenium gui , there you have an option of converting ur step to java code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Selenium jars into JMeter's /lib folder? If not - copy them there, restart JMeter and retry.

By the way, there is [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) which could be more handy for Selenium and JMeter integration.

If you decide to go JUnit way I would recommend adding debug command line argument to JMeter startup script, something like

```
set JVM_ARGS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 %JVM_ARGS%
```

After that you can connect to JMeter JVM instance with Eclipse and,  what exactly is "null" and resolve it. See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more clues and exact configuration instructions for JMeter and Eclipse sides.

Comment: Did it all, and have a new error:
Error -- testTestLoad(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase): Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Comment: And by the way, I'm working throw VPN, I have some tool on my PC to connect to the server

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict between JMeter and Selenium dependencies, try installing WebDriver Sampler plugin on clean JMeter and see how it goes

Comment: Deleted all old jars in Jmeter/lib. Now when I start Threed, browser open but nothing else. Here's a screenshot on issue:
http://prntscr.com/7frrrp
and my dependency in pom.xml:
http://prntscr.com/7frsu1

Comment: It looks like that you're trying to use Firefox 38 with Selenium 2.35.0. According to Selenium changelog the maximum supported Firefox version for Selenium 2.35.0 is Firefox 23. Get Firefox 23 from [Mozilla FTP site](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox), it should solve your problem. See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide "How do I Know Which Browsers are Supported?" section to learn how to find match between Selenium and Firefox versions.

Comment: yes, it was because of old version of firefox-webdriver. I used 1.44 except 1.6. Now everything is good, it works :) But I have new problem, how to realize here multythreading?

Comment: JMeter is multithreaded by design, just add more threads (virtual users) on Thread Group level

Comment: yes, I can do this, but right now I need just 5 user, then 10, 15 , 25 and 50 users, and It's not a good idea to create a lot of jar files with difference users, better will be do this changes in code, and I'll have just one JAR file.

Do you know how to realize it? Cus I made some changes but it's not working

Comment: it's because I have for example 5 users (different user), because I can't test it with one user, cus I'll have an error, cus at the time can't working with one user, the'll be an error message in browser. So that's why I need to use multythreading in my class, and will be good if it'll take login from some file.

Comment: I did the multithreading. Except login selection for this method:

 testTestLoad()

Comment: You can use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read credentials from file and access JMeter Variables like `new JUnitSampler().getThreadContext().getVariables().get("foo");`. See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide (Accessing JMeter Variables from the JUnit Test Case section) for details